# have fields in cloudcontainerdatabase unique over all entities?

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit

I have the following fields in two entities. the uniqueID would be created via code but both fields are not matching together.

in the toolsEntity, i have the uniqueID for other datas in a second entity. The uniqueID in the ToolsSectionsEntity are matching in the code with the sectionUniqueID.

```
RECORD TYPE CD_ToolsEntity (
CD_ankle             DOUBLE QUERYABLE SORTABLE,
CD_cuttingToolHolder STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
CD_entityName        STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
CD_favoriteFrontbase INT64 QUERYABLE SORTABLE,
CD_imagename         STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
CD_inGrindDirection  INT64 QUERYABLE SORTABLE,
CD_name              STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
CD_remark            STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
CD_sectionUniqueID   STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
CD_sectionUniqueName STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
CD_uniqueID          STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
"___createTime"      TIMESTAMP,
"___createdBy"       REFERENCE,
"___etag"            STRING,
"___modTime"         TIMESTAMP,
"___modifiedBy"      REFERENCE,
"___recordID"        REFERENCE,
GRANT WRITE TO "_creator",
GRANT CREATE TO "_icloud",
GRANT READ TO "_world"
);

RECORD TYPE CD_ToolsSectionsEntity (
CD_sectionName  STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
CD_uniqueID     STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
"___createTime" TIMESTAMP,
"___createdBy"  REFERENCE,
"___etag"       STRING,
"___modTime"    TIMESTAMP,
"___modifiedBy" REFERENCE,
"___recordID"   REFERENCE,
GRANT WRITE TO "_creator",
GRANT CREATE TO "_icloud",
GRANT READ TO "_world"
);
```

When I insert a tooldata, then the synchronization works fine.

When I add a section into the table ToolsSectionsEntity, then the synchronization stops. Could it be that I have to change the name of the field in ToolsSectionsEntity.uniqueID to ToolsSectionsEntity.toolsSectionUniqueID, that in the hole datafieldlist be only one "uniqueID"?

I have reinstalled the app and test if the synchronization works, when i dont touch the toolsSectionsEntity. And it still works.